# The "go" keyword in Go

Tags: go

Here is the code example in "A Tour of Go" [Range and Close](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func fibonacci(n int, c chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        c <- x
        x, y = y, x+y
    }
    close(c)
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 10)
    go fibonacci(cap(c), c)
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

On the fifth line from the bottom, when the `go` keyword was omitted, the result did not change. Did that mean the main goroutine sent values in the buffered channel and then took them out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of it like this:

With the `go` keyword, the `fibonacci` function is adding numbers onto the channel and the `for i := range c` loop is printing each number out *as soon* as it is added to the channel.

Without the `go` keyword, the `fibonacci` function is called, adds *all* the numbers to the channel, and then returns, and *then* the `for` loop prints the numbers off the `channel`.

One good way to see this is to put in a sleep ([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/0oNDy65N5t)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func fibonacci(n int, c chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        time.Sleep(time.Second) // ADDED THIS SLEEP
        c <- x
        x, y = y, x+y
    }
    close(c)
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 10)
    go fibonacci(cap(c), c) // TOGGLE BETWEEN THIS
    // fibonacci(cap(c), c) // AND THIS
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, a more technical explanation could mention that `go` keyword actually starts a method in a separate thread :)

Comment: it MAY start a method in a separate thread.  Or it could do it in the same thread but switch between the main goroutine and the newly spawned fibonacci goroutine.  It is a minor point, but just wanted to make sure it is not confused with actual OS level threads.